# Removing any two array values whose difference is a member of that array

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am trying to remove array values whose difference is a member of that array in MATLAB. For example, if I have an array defined as

```
x = [1 2 4 3 7];
```

I would like to remove 2, because it can be achieved from 4 - 2. I would also like to remove 4 because it can be achieved from 7 - 3. I would then like to store these values (2 and 4, respectively) into a matrix. The latter is easy. I just have a hard time doing this checker for summation.

I know you can use

```
ismember(*any 2 differences*),x(:))
```

to check if the differences are in the array. However, I don't know how to code my function to try out all the combinations of element subtraction.

Comment: Shouldn't `1` be removed too, because `2-1=1`? Also, `7-4=3`, so remove `3` too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seemed like a good setup to use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) -

```
abs_diffs = abs(bsxfun(@minus,x(:),x(:).'))  %//'

unq_abs_diffs = unique(abs_diffs)

out = x(~any(bsxfun(@eq,unq_abs_diffs(:),x(:).'),1))   %//'
%// OR x(~ismember(x,unq_abs_diffs))
```

Sample run -

```
>> x
x =
     1     2     4     3     7
>> abs_diffs = abs(bsxfun(@minus,x(:),x(:).'))
abs_diffs =
     0     1     3     2     6
     1     0     2     1     5
     3     2     0     1     3
     2     1     1     0     4
     6     5     3     4     0
>> unq_abs_diffs = unique(abs_diffs)
unq_abs_diffs =
     0
     1
     2
     3
     4
     5
     6
>> out = x(~any(bsxfun(@eq,unq_abs_diffs(:),x(:).'),1))
out =
     7
```

So, in `[1 2 4 3 7]`, only `7` seemed like the one that could not be removed.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
n = length(a);
differences = meshgrid(a,a) - meshgrid(a,a)'; % get differences between elements
differences(1:n+1:n*n) = []; % remove diagonal
a(ismember(a,differences)) = []; % remove elements in differences
```

I'm assuming that you only want differences between unique elements. If you want to allow the difference between an element of `a` and itself, then remove the 3rd line.